# Ubuntu 32bit version installed using wubi, on drive e, same hard drive, error "no root file system defined"

Tags: partitioning

First time giving this a shot, seems like fun and its free. So originally I installed Ubuntu 64bit version on drive E, from windows xp using wubi. I read somewhere that I can use teh installer for the 32bit version as I was having a hard time installing from the cd/dvd I made, and it wont allow me to install on the partition (drive E) when installing from cd/dvd.
So after installing onto this drive E, during the reboot, it gets into ubuntu, but has an error during the installation and I cannot do anything from there on out. I checked the partition, and the files are there. If 64bit version worked fine, why would this issue arise on the 32bit, same drive, same partition, same method? I really want to mess around with this, and set up this older machine with ubuntu only. AMD athlon 64 3700, 2.2 mghtz, 2gb of ram, 500gbhdd, ati vid card 1gb ram, gigabyte mobo.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use 32bit version when the 64bit world?

That said, Do the 32bit version finish ok? If not, you may have been effected by a bug in the 32bit installer, which is corrected by uninstall a package. It Is shown by that the ending presentation of Ubuntu during installation isn't shown and the installation is ended prematurly.
The 64bit installer doesn't have this error.

More information about that problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139362/ubuntu-12-04-lts-installer-crashes-due-to-system-log-file-error